# Wordpress - Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm learning how to make Setting API Options in WordPress but every time add a code into my functions.php file it brings up this error.

How do I fix this?

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_plugin_menu' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-test-sites/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525 

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_plugin_menu' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-test-sites/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525 

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_plugin_menu' not found or invalid function name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-test-sites/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 525
```

Comment: Please edit your post with your code so we have something to review.

Comment: Light corrected grammar an formatting